# Location of My Pictures

Tags: c#, windows, windows-vista, windows-xp

How do I programatically (Using C#) find out what the path is of my My Pictures folder?

Does this work on XP and Vista?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The following will return a full-path to the location of the users picture folder (Username\My Documents\My Pictures on XP, Username\Pictures on Vista)

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
```

Answer (score 6):

Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);

Answer (score 0):

Using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SpecialDirectories.MyPictures you can get that, works in vista and XP.